Swagger 404 error for login page using on-prem windows AD authentication
I am trying to create a login page with windows authentication using on-prem AD. The application itself is a .Net 8 WebApi with a react front end. When I run the application, I get the login page and the swagger UI but when I post to the api I get a 404 error. I think the issue might be the app config within the Program.cs file but I am lost here. Any advice or tips on how to make this work would be appreciated. Below is the code.
Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.BearerToken;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyApp.Server.Data;
using MyApp.Server.Models;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace MyApp.Server
{
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Login"; });;

        var configuration = new 
        ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => 
        options.UseMySQL(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5173/");
                });
        });

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "api",
            pattern: "{controller=api}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();
        app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

        app.Run();
    }
  }
}

LoginController
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.Server.Models;

namespace MyApp.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Index")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(LoginModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, 
                "CompanyDomain"))
                {
                    if (pc.ValidateCredentials(model.userName, model.password))
                    {
                        var up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, 
                        IdentityType.SamAccountName, model.userName);

                        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, up.Name) };
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, model.userName));

                        foreach (var ag in up.GetAuthorizationGroups())
                            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ag.Name));

                        var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

                        ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
                        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(cp);

                        return Ok("Success!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                return BadRequest("Failed!");
            }

            return BadRequest("Failed!");
        }
    }
}

Login.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Login() {
    // state variable for user name and passwords
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState<string>("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");

    //state variable for error messages
    const [error, setError] = useState<string>("");
    /*const navigate = useNavigate();*/

    // handle change events for input fields
    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        if (name === "userName") setUserName(value);
        if (name === "password") setPassword(value);
    };

    // handle submit event for the form
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // validate user name and password
        if (!userName || !password) {
            setError("Please fill in all fields.");
        } else {
            // clear error message
            setError("");

            var loginurl = "";
            loginurl = "/Login/Index";

            fetch(loginurl, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "Application/json",
                    "Accept": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    userName: userName,
                    password: password,
                }),
            })
                .then((data) => {
                    // handle success or error from the server
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.ok) {
                        setError("Successful login.");
                    }
                    else
                        setError("Error logging in.");
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // handle network error
                    console.error(error);
                    setError("Error logging in.");
                });
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="containerbox">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label className="forminput" htmlFor="userName">User Name:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="name" id="userName" name="userName" value={userName} onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={handleChange} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
        </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

Login Model
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Server.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your username.")]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your password.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}

appsetting.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=dbname;Initial Catalog=dbcatalog; user=#; password=#"
  },
}


I have found the root cause and share with you below, by the way, the middleware order in your project is terrible, please check the official document, have a nice day.

The root cause is your are adding global policy for all the controllers.
builder.Services.AddControllers(config =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});

You can test it by using builder.Services.AddControllers(), it will works properly.
In your scenario, the login method should not require an authenticated user to be accessible, so you can use [AllowAnonymous] to fix the issue.

This did fix some of the issue.

Hi @JavaFox In this case, the main issue is 404 error. If you have another issue, I suggest addressing each on a case-by-case basis by posting a new post for every separate case. Thanks.
